# Memory locations, and ranges

Tags: c, memory, struct, bit

Say I have a struct:

```
struct guitar{
   long guitarID;
   short brand:3;
   short strings: 6;
   short price;
}x[5][5]; //Thanks chux
```

If the address of x is 0xaaa and memory is aligned at multiples of 4 then what would the address be at x[1]?

The other thing I want to know is what the range of numbers between brand and strings are now that they are affected by a bitfield?

Comment: `...  short price; };x[5][5]` is a problem.  `... short price; } x[5][5];` make more sense.

Comment: "memory is aligned at multiples of 4" and "x is 0xaaa" is contradictory as `0xaaa` is not a multiple of 4. So alignment at multiples of 4 is not happening or `0xaaa` is a fiction.

Comment: How about starting with doing some experiments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming long 8 bytes, short 2 bytes and memory is 4 bytes aligned size of struct is 8 byte + 3 bit + 6 bit + 2 byte = 8 + 4 = 12 bytes.

x[1] is nothing but &x[1][0].

If x is 0xaaa , x[1] is 0xaaa + (5 * 12) = 0xaaa + 60.

So x[1] is 60 bytes away from x.

Comment: I was under the influence that the long is 4 bytes. Why do you assume it's 8?

Comment: This varies, for example in a 64 bit machine linux ubuntu 14 long is 8 bytes. It is not fixed one.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to compute it. The first thing you need to know the size of the struct. Since the size is implementation dependent let's consider a 32-bit machine.

The first member of your structure, guitarID, has 4 bytes. Then, you have 3 bits in brand, 6 bits in strings. These 2, along with padding, make up another 2 bytes. And then, you have another 2 bytes in price. In total, your structure occupies 8 bytes.

Now, let's see how your array is stored. You have a matrix of 5 by 5 elements. In memory, it is stored linearly, like this:

x[0][0] x[0][1] x[0][2] x[0][3] x[0][4] x[1][0] x[1][1] x[1][2] x[1][3]

and so on. I don't know exactly what you mean by x[1], but I assume that you're interested in the address of x[1][0]. You can see that it has before it 5 elements, which means that is has an address with 5 * 8 = 40 bytes higher than the address of the first element. I cannot give you an absolute address as an answer, since 0xaaa which you mentioned as an address for the first element is not word aligned.